# How to achieve evenly spaced layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My current layout looks the following:

[image]

MY XML layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLetter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/letter_size"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/bd" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/colorButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_action"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_action"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background ="@drawable/colors"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/soundButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_action"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_action"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sound" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eraserButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_action"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_action"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/eraser" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/letter_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/letter_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/zebra" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionHolder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wordSound"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_action"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_action"
            android:background="@drawable/sound" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My `@dimen/letter_icon` is being used for different sizes based on the screen size. I am trying to make it compatible with both phone and tablet (different size screen). How do I achieve the following in my layout:

[image]

Let's say the ZEBRA text is inside a textview and the sound is in a button.

I am thinking the bottom ImageView has to be inside another layout, linearleayout maybe? and take up 3/4 of the space of the screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `ZEBRA` and `SPEAKER` buttons in vertical `LinearLayout`. Set buttons' `height` to `match_parent` and `layout_weight` to `1` and you should have what you want

and if you want to distribute width among your buttons' container and ImageView, set them `width` to `match_parent` and play with `layout_weight` there.

Comment: Should I put the ZEBRA picture inside another layout so it center the icon and doesn't change the size if another icon is different?

Comment: you can, if you do not want to play with ImageView's scaleType etc. The less elements then layout is processed faster, but from the other hands on nowadays 1GB phones it makes no real difference.

Comment: What's confusing me is the part of me trying to make sure it appears same across different screen devices. I want to get them all equal widthXheight using `@dimen`

Comment: I didnt want to use hardcoded size because not all screen size are the same. I took a different approach and got it to work a little differently. Thanks for answering my question.